# Update same field in multiple documents with data from json

Tags: json, mongodb

I have a MongoDB looking like this:

```
[
    {
        "status" : 0,
        "name" : "Yaknow",
        "email" : "yaknow@not.this",
        "_id" : "5875a42ea469f40c684de385"
    },
    {
        "status" : 1,
        "name" : "johnk",
        "email" : "johnk@not@this",
        "_id" : "586e31c6ce07af6f891f80fd"
    }
]
```

Meanwhile, all the emails have changed and I got a Json with the new ones:

```
[
    {
        "email" : "yaknow@gmai.new",
        "_id" : "5875a42ea469f40c684de385"
    },
    {
        "email" : "johnk@gmail.new",
        "_id" : "586e31c6ce07af6f891f80fd"
    }
]
```

How do I update all the emails?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no operator in mongodb which allows you modify string value by replacing some part of string. You should get documents, and then [for each](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.forEach/) of documents you should locally prepare updated value and update document:

```
db.collection.find({}).forEach(function(doc){ 
    var newEmail = doc.email.substr(0, doc.email.indexOf('@')) + "@gmail.new";
    db.collection.update({_id: doc._id}, {$set:{email: newEmail}}); 
});
```

Comment: I ended just deleting and inserting everything. It was simpler in my specific situation (witch is, in itself, weird...)